# Numpy 3d (voxels) erosion

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, voxel

I have 3d boolean (numpy) array where element is True if a voxel is present. On an object in this 3d array I want to perform erosion ('eat away the edges', 2d example for [OpenCV here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html)). I know I can do this by iterating over all elements, but this is very slow.

Is there in Numpy/Scipy a way more native/faster way of achieving this?

Comment: Your link is broken. Should end on html :). (Can't edit because it's less than 6 characters!)

Comment: Fixed the link. :-)

Comment: have you considered using [multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erosion is a rather costly operation. You can try [scipy's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) implementation. I'm not sure how it is implemented.

If you end up using it, please get back with a performance update :).